# Leaflet WMS Tile Layer bounds set

Tags: leaflet, geoserver, react-leaflet

I want to limit my wms tile layers with a region. I saw a parameter in the WMSTileLayer bounds, however it can't be usable it always gives an error lat long.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined
```

It looks like wms tile layer not overlapping with coordinates. I set the srs option such a below

```
  <WMSTileLayer
    layers={tile.layer}
    format='image/png8'
    version='1.3'
    url={tile.url}
    tiled={true}
    bounds={tile.bounds}
    time={tile.date}
    transparent={true}
    zIndex={tile.zIndex}
    srs={CRS.EPSG4326}
  />
```

and bounds

```
      bounds: [
        [27.5, 37.5],
        [28.24, 37.9]
      ]
```

Geoserver configuration can be shown in the image.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpQgI.png]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

WMSTileLayer inherits from L.TileLayer, which inherits from L.GridLayer.  The `bounds` option is an instance of [`L.LatLngBounds`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#gridlayer-bounds), but you have it as an array of numbers.  You need to [construct a latLngBounds](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#latlngbounds) from your bounds:

```js
const { bounds } = tile
// bounds:
// [
//  [27.5, 37.5],
//  [28.24, 37.9]
// ]

const latLng1 = L.latLng(bounds[0]);
const latLng2 = L.latLng(bounds[1]);

const myLatLngBounds = L.latLngBounds(latLng1, latLng2);
```

Now you can use that in the `bounds` prop of the WMSTileLayer:

```js
 <WMSTileLayer
    ...
    bounds={myLatLngBounds}
    ...
  />
```

Comment: Hi @Seth, I tried this. However it doesn't work. Actually I'm aware of bounds can be used as array such as map bounds we can give latlongbounds as an array. Also Typescript can also translate this object to latlngbounds class. Do you have any suggestion about this topic. I observed wms works accurate however leaflet overwrite the bounds with respect to map.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, you mean you're still getting the same error?  Can you add the error stack trace to the question?

Comment: No, error isn't exist however bounds are changing with map bounds instead of i gave.

Comment: Ok...that sounds like a whole different problem.  Without understand the full scope of your setup, I can't really diagnose that problem.  Perhaps you can add more code, or reproduce the problem in a codepen / codesandbox